# How does a margin account work?

Tags: investing, broker

If you open a margin account, does this mean that you are putting your OWN money in the margin account which is supervised by a broker and to whom you pay interest to?

Answer (score 2):

A margin account is one where you can borrow money from your broker to buy securities.  The loan is collateralized by your cash and/or marginable securities.  You pay interest to the broker on cash borrowed.  However, you do not have to borrow cash from your broker.

Some strategies cannot be done in a cash account and require a margin account: shorting securities, selling uncovered options...

A managed account is one that is supervised by a broker, to whom you a fee.  The fee tends to be an annual percentage of the value of your account.